# How to promote a byte by specific value?

Tags: c#, byte

So i have this file that i am opening:

```
static void Encrypt(string fileName)
{
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
            {
                byte b = reader.ReadByte();
                byte newByte = (byte(b + 5))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And i want to add specific value to each byte in my file and save it.

Comment: "save it"? What do you mean? Do you mean to overwrite the original byte in the same stream or into a new stream/file? Also, please post the real code, as it stands now it won't compile because `(byte(b + 5))` is not a real expression, and then we don't know what else you've removed/replaced either.

Comment: Are you trying to implement some kind of ROT encryption?

Comment: i want to save it to new file, newByte was only example that i try to do (not even compile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just store the new bytes in a collection and save them after reading whole file.

```
var newBytes = new List<byte>();
...
for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
{
    byte b = reader.ReadByte();
    newBytes.Add(b + 5);
}
...

File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, newBytes.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
byte b = reader.ReadByte();
int newNumber = (int)b + 5;
byte newByte = (byte)(newNumber % 256);
```

To have control over the overflow you may create, I suggest you change from `byte` to `int`.

Then this adds 5 to the byte value you read, wrapping to zero when you reach `b == 251`, as `251 + 5 == 256` and `256 % 256 == 0`.